# Why is this java code not running the class and printing the values? I have tried a lot but not able to find a way out

Tags: java, methods

```
class pizza {

public int pizza (int price, int discount) {   

int total = 0; 

total = price - discount; 

return total; 
} 
}
public class MyClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int itemNum; 

int price;  

String pizName; 

boolean extraCheese;

itemNum = 1101; 

pizName = "Pepperoni"; 

extraCheese = false; 

System.out.println ("Your order a" +pizName+ "pizza will be served shortly.");

pizza pepperoni = new pizza (50, 10);

System.out.println("Your payment without discount is:" + pepperoni.price); 

}

}
```

This is my code above any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much guys. Java is a general-purpose computer-programming language that is concurrent, class-based, object-oriented, and specifically designed to have as few implementation dependencies as possible.

Comment: Please format your code properly, and remove the spam text. If you're running this code, it will print, so you must not be running it properly. Show how it's being run.

Comment: Even before running the code, your code will not even compile. It will show error on lines `new pizza(50, 10);` and `pepperoni.price`.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the method and class should not be same. You are trying to initialise instance variable using constructor. But the syntax for the constructor is not correct and also it implicitly returns reference to the object.